# peripheral writeValue: forCharacteristic: type: return null error and value

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am using the code below written by Apple.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/HeartRateMonitor/Listings/HeartRateMonitor_HeartRateMonitorAppDelegate_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011322-HeartRateMonitor_HeartRateMonitorAppDelegate_m-DontLinkElementID_4

Here is the writeValue section written by Apple

```
if ([aChar.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"2A39"]])
{
  uint8_t val = 1;
  NSData* valData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(void*)&val length:sizeof(val)];
  [aPeripheral writeValue:valData forCharacteristic:aChar type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
}
```

I added didWriteValueForCharacteristic

```
- (void) peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didWriteValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
  NSLog(@"Did write characteristic value : %@ with ID %@", characteristic.value, characteristic.UUID);
  NSLog(@"With error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

The print out from didWriteValueForCharacteristic is the following:

```
Did write characteristic value : (null) with ID Unknown (<2a39>)
With error: (null)
```

I have used two different heart monitors and Blue Light app (simulates ble device) but I get the same outcome.

Why do I get null back for the value and error for didWriteValueForCharacteristic?

Comment: Error will be null if the write was successful. Please see @allprog of why the value is zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see is the last read value of the characteristic. Since you never read it before, it is `nil`. You need to explicitly read the value to get it updated on the central side with the `readValueForCharacteristic:` method.

Comment: Thanks. Where should I put the readValueforCharacteristic? I added the readValueForCharacteristic after writeValue but that did not work. What happens if the characteristic is write characteristic and not a read/write one? Many thanks!

Comment: You can read the characteristic only if it's readable. If not readable, then you cannot obtain its value. You should read the value after the write has been confirmed by the didWriteValueForCharacteristic callback. E.g. use dispatch_async to start the call after the return from the callback. You can look this up with a simple internet search. If I answered your question, please accept it.